# PCL Acr.UserDialogs. Custom styling for android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am using Acr.UserDialogs plugin in my Xamarin MvvmCross project. 
And everything was fine, but found that on Android 7.0 Alert dialogs has invisible Ok button (on previous versions it's displayed correctly).

I found only the way to redefine style, through AndroidResourceId property, when creating Alert dialog, but in my case this dialogs are created in PCL:

```
await userDialogs.AlertAsync(new AlertConfig { Message = message });
```

So it's not suitable for me to hardcode resourceId (they are regenerated, and common PCL embedded resources is a bad idea).

I tryed to implement my own class, derived from UserDialogImpl, or AbstractUserDialog, but there's a problem with resolving Activity in constructor.

I initialize dialogs in a such way:

```
UserDialogs.Init(() => Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity);
userDialogs = Mvx.Resolve<IUserDialogs>();
```

Saw, there is also an action parameter, passed to AlertAsync, but cannot find a way to handle it in android project.

Is there another way to customize a style for userDialog in android project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a dialog theme...

```
<style name="YourDialogThemeHere" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog">
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

...then you can theme *all* of the dialogs in one go like this in your Droid project:

```
   var dialogStyle = Resource.Style.YourDialogThemeHere;
   AlertConfig.DefaultAndroidStyleId = dialogStyle;
   PromptConfig.DefaultAndroidStyleId = dialogStyle;
   ConfirmConfig.DefaultAndroidStyleId = dialogStyle;
   ActionSheetConfig.DefaultAndroidStyleId = dialogStyle;
   DatePromptConfig.DefaultAndroidStyleId = dialogStyle;
   TimePromptConfig.DefaultAndroidStyleId = dialogStyle;
   LoginConfig.DefaultAndroidStyleId = dialogStyle;
```

If you want to react to the dialog in the Droid project then you can send a message from the PCL project using the MvvmCross Messenger plugin. The platform specific view can subscribe to the message while the PCL project publishes the message.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I forget about this question already, as soon as found a solution. Solved in a similiar way, based on forced setting of a style with colorAccent in activity.